# Running Interstitial ad from SliderLayout

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have an Interstitial ad in my application, when i show the ad in `onCreate()` it works.
Now i'm using a library to make image slider with Glide library, i want to display the ad after 20 scrolls of images.

i used a counter to determine the number of images scrolled and then show the ad.

This is the initialize and creation of Interstitial and AdRequest

```
InterstitialAd interstitial;
AdRequest adRequest;
SliderLayout slider;

int count=0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);

    slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(SliderActivity.this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_interisial));
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("7B7D134FF9931565B8C442934E12A0C1").build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
```

and the slider provides listener for Scrolling pages here is the code i wrote

```
slider.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener()   {


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {


            count++;
            System.out.println("count = " + count);
            if(count %20 == 0){

                        System.out.println("twenty times");
                        displayInterstitial();


            }


        }
    });
```

and here is `displayInterstitial()` method

```
public void displayInterstitial() { 
    if (interstitial.isLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.show();
    } 
}
```

When i scrolled 20 images the code prints "twenty times", but the ad not loaded.

Did i miss anything?
 Why does this problem happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                            public void onAdLoaded(){
                                System.out.println("adLoaded");

                                interstitial.show();
                            }
                        });
```

you need to add this listener in `onCreate()` method.
And change the content of method `displayInterstitial()`like below :

```
public void displayInterstitial() { 
    if (!interstitial.isLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It seems like that it should work, but actually it didn't.

Comment: it will take time to load add as per your internet connection speed.
You didn't put add listener in your oncreate() method.

Comment: it worked, the problem was from admob console. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because of ad is loaded before pager comes to 20 count.

When you are calling `interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);` then after some time you can see by print logs that onLoaded called this and `if(count %20 == 0)` return false.

**Solution**

You have to set ad load listener before calling `loadAd`.

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener()
{
    public void onAdLoaded()
    {
        System.out.println("adLoaded");
        isAdLoaded = true;
    }
}
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And display ad in `onPageSelected`

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {

    count++;
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
    if(isAdLoaded && count%20 == 0){

            isAdLoaded = false;
            System.out.println("twenty times");
            displayInterstitial();
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: It should work, there will be some other issue. I checked this code.